# Bend and break, the breaking part

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

See http://www.jstor.org/stable/1971241?seq=6#page_scan_tab_contents, pages 598 and 599.

Suppose we have $\pi: \widetilde Y \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X\times \overline D \rightarrow \overline D$, where $\widetilde Y \rightarrow Y$ is the normalization (which is finite -- we are working with varieties). Suppose furthermore that every fiber is a (single) rational curve $\pi ^{-1}(d), d \in \overline D$.

We want to reach a contradiction. To do this, we require an isomorphism from a dense open subset of $\widetilde Y_d$ to its image in $Y_d$ (for any $d \in \overline D$). According to Mori, this is the case because the singular locus of $Y$ does not contain any fiber of $Y$ over $\overline D$.

Why does it not contain any fiber? How does this guarantee the isomorphism?

Comment: It seems that, if $Y_d$ was in $Y_{\text{sing}}$, this would allow $\widetilde Y \rightarrow Y$ to be ramified at $Y_d$. If we can show that this is necessarily the case, this would be then contradict our assumption that $\pi^{-1}(d)$ is irreducible.